# How to set a default value for a Select component from react with MenuItem as options

Tags: reactjs, select, menuitem

I've been wondering how to set the default value of a Select in React when we use the MenuItem component as options.

First, I get an user list with the following useEffect that returns a list of users (objects with id, firstName and lastName among other attributes)

```
  const [userList, setUserList] = useState([]);
  //Get users
  useEffect(() => {
    userService
    .listUsersFromTeamRHandAdmin()
      .then((res) => {
        setUserList(res)
    });
  }, [])
  
  const {
    setFieldValue
  } = useFormikContext();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFieldValue("user.id", setUserList[e.target.value].id)
  }
```

I have the following Select component, where I would like to have the first user's id of the UserList as a default value, with this user's firstname and lastname displayed.

```
<Select
    name="user"
    defaultValue={userList[0].id || ''}
    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
    style={{
        width: "100%",
        marginBottom: "1em"
    }}
>
    {
        Object.keys(userList).map((e, keyIndex) => {
            return (
                <MenuItem key={keyIndex} value={e}>
                    {userList[e].firstName} {userList[e].lastName}
                </MenuItem>
            );
        })
    }
</Select>
```

Does anyone know how I can do that ?

Edit:

For example, the array of UserList would contain something like:

```
0: Object { id: 1, firstName: "Britta", lastName: "Perry", … }
​
1: Object { id: 2, firstName: "Troy", lastName: "Barnes", … }
```

Comment: Please provide example of userList array's data when it's not empty, then we can help you

Comment: I added an edit, hoping that's what you wanted :)

Comment: thank's, when you try this  defaultValue={{ id: 1, firstName: "Britta", lastName: "Perry", … }} did you get Britta Perry as a default value ?

Comment: What's the ui library that you are using for the Select component ?

Comment: Trying to fill with the user didn't change anything and I am using the material UI library :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a defaultValue in the MaterialUi Select Component you should provide a defaultValue that exist in your choices, please try this :

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { Select, MenuItem } from "@mui/material";
export default function App() {
  const arr = [
    { id: 1, firstName: "Britta", lastName: "Perry" },
    { id: 2, firstName: "Troy", lastName: "Barnes" }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        name="user"
        defaultValue={arr[0].firstName + arr[0].lastName || ""}
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          marginBottom: "1em"
        }}
      >
        {arr.map((el) => (
          <MenuItem key={el.id} value={el.firstName + el.lastName}>
            {el.firstName + el.lastName}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see, the defaultValue and the menuItem have the same syntaxe, [this a working demo that I've created for this](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-shadow-o4ys28?file=/src/App.js:0-796)

you can add separator between firstName and lastName but keep the same syntaxe in defaultValue too.